# Collapse address fields for account statement

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a sheet with 7 fields:

```
Name 1
Name 2
Street Address 1
Street Address 2
City
State 
Zip
```

There is a multitude of possibilities with the above between company name, c/o name, Unit# or no Unit#, etc.  Another sheet is an account statement which needs to look clean.  What formulas can I put in the account statement address fields to automatically remove empty fields with no information?

I've tried a bunch of if and isblank formulas, but its tough to wrap my head around it - maybe theres another way?

[image: Example]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13h5BfcbuO6XLTIQJzmV0WtS6ogL9kwQREH1G-qPIAd0/edit?usp=sharing  I figured out a way to do it in columns P and Q but if i can get the sheet without that, itd be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({'9102-1000 Doe'!C3:C4;
  '9102-1000 Doe'!D3:D4;
  '9102-1000 Doe'!D5&", "&'9102-1000 Doe'!D6&" "&'9102-1000 Doe'!D7}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

[image: 0]